# How to add a custom field to the Project administration page using the FogBugz plugin API?

Tags: c#, plugins, projects, fogbugz, fogbugz-api

I'd like to add a custom field to Projects in FogBugz and have that field show up in the project administration page.  This way, when a user creates a new project, or edits an old one, the field can be edited immediately.

My only other alternative would be to create a custom page with a form for associating the field specifically, but this creates a great deal of disconnect and could result in users forgetting to set the setting.

Is this even possible?  I'm new to the FogBugz plugin API and wanted to make sure it was possible before wasting too much time researching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible. Check out these interfaces in the documentation to get started:

- IPluginProjectDisplay
- IPluginProjectCommit

BTW: You might have more luck with questions on FogBugz and plugin development on the [FogBugz StackExchange site](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/).